# Problem with duration formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having a bit of a problem with this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(H13:H17, ">="&A30, H13:H17, "<"&A31)
```

I'm trying to count the number of Duration occurrences, from 0 to 30 min in 1 min intervals. But here's the problem I run into. If I use it on the cell where I just put the time by myself like `0:01:15 (HH:MM:SS)`, then it works just fine.

But the problem is that I don't want to count durations manually. And in another line, I have two timestamps and just use a simple formula to get the difference ( duration). And that's where the problem starts. If I use the same formula on the cell where the duration is calculated automatically, I get different results.

Any recommendations on how to fix it?

Comment: can you add a screen shot of a sample of the data including column headers and cell letters?

Comment: I posted a sample sheet as the answer below. But here it is again. [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G82RJEdxkieGZldUhLNxaqcVSfbS1jbX3sWPxYDOUUQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing rounding inconsistencies in the representation of time (why I do not recommend the Duration format). However, if I understand your requirement (I am not sure I do) then in C2 and copied down to suit:

```
=ROUND(B2-A2,15)
```

and in E2 and copied down to suit:

```
=round((row()-2)/(60*24),15)
```

may provide you the automation you seek.

Comment: That worked great. Can you explain what 15 means in the formula. Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

format all times as `TIME` and all durations as `DURATION` by clicking on **<kbd>123</kbd>** button

[image]